# is there a way to configure paritally or fully serializion to json using jersey?

Tags: java, json, file, serialization, jersey

I want to serialize a java object using jersey.

I want to serialize it and print it to file.

It's a big object and i want to save it twice:

one in a short version with mandatory fields only.

second in full version with all fields.

Is there a way to do so, other than create two DTOs

and duplicate the small object from the big object and then serialize them both to json?

Comment: using Jersey is mandatory or you could add Jackson ? If you could do that, may be adding a custom serializer will be the solution. Check this link http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: thanks. what is the purpose of jersey vs. the purpose of jackson?

can i use the `custom serializer` to create non flat objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it fast, Jersey help making REST webservices and Jackson help to manage a JSON Object.
So you can use both and have more ways to play with your objects.

Extending the JsonSerializer you could provide 2 custom serializer with the behaviour you want. I don't repost the link i put in comment, but there's an example in it.
Just to be sure, for me a non flat object is an object with private attributes that are business object to. If it is, yes, you could serialize a non flat object.

To serialize non flat objects, in my opinion there are two ways. And i based my development on the link i provided in comments (Item, User, Main class...).
First one, the composed one are simple so i could use something like this :

```
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("itemName", value.itemName);

        jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("owner");
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.owner.id);
        jgen.writeStringField("name", value.owner.name);
        jgen.writeEndObject();

        jgen.writeEndObject();
```

In this case, the owner is composed with two fields, pretty simple.

The second solution is to use one another serializer : 
One for main object, one for the composite and use :

```
jgen.writeObjectField("owner.", value.owner);
```

and don't forget to add the composed object serializer with :

```
module.addSerializer(User.class, new UserSerializer());
```

hope this help

Comment: non flat I mean composite object. with non primitive members

Comment: great, that's the way i understood it

Comment: can you please add an example? I see only falt objects example: `{
    "id": 25,
    "itemName": "FEDUfRgS",
    "owner": 15
}`

Comment: how would it be for serializing lists?

Comment: with using writeArrayFieldStart then writeObject for all the fields of the list and finish by a writeEndArray.

Comment: `The second solution is to use one another serializer` where is the second defined?

Comment: One serializer for the item, and one for the User